# error on exiting a window

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

In the following picture, when i click File->New Game I see this window:
[image]

If i continue and press Start Game, everything works great. But if i just click the red X, i get this error:
[image]

This is the code for File->New Game:

```
private: System::Void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        NG->ShowDialog();
        ShowPossible();
        update_score();
        if(pc_exists()==1)
            ComputerPlay();
    }
```

`NG->ShowDialog()` shows the New Game dialog.

And then `ShowPossible()` shows something on the board (hints for possible moves).
And that's what's making trouble.
I need some code that quits from `newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click()` on X click instead of continuing to `ShowPossible()`.

I tried making a global variable called `ready` in form `NewGame`, and at form load initialized it with 0, and only when i click Start Game it turns to 1. And finally added this condition in the above function:

```
...
if(ready)
    ShowPossible();
...
```

So this way if i don't click Start Game, and only click X, `ready` will be 0 and it won't enter `ShowPossible()`. But it didn't work. Somehow when the code for the button Start Game finishes, ready is still 0.

Is there any more efficient way to deal with this?

Thank you !

Comment: [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) Return Value
Type: System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
One of the DialogResult values.

Comment: Click `break` and see where the error is in the debugger.

Comment: @RetiredNinja But i said the problem is that it goes into ShowPossible(). I guess that means i clicked `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

Since you are using `System.Windows.Forms`, check against the `DialogResult` enumeration (Thanks chris):

```
if (NG->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Cancel)
    return;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close
>   button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form)
>   causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set
>   to DialogResult.Cancel.

Comment: I would check it against the proper enumeration value.

Comment: Sounds good. I didn't know `ShowDialog()` returns a value. But now i get this error:
`error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: `DialogResult.Cancel` gives this error: `error C2039: 'Cancel' : is not a member of 'System::Enum'`. I tried `DialogResult->Cancel` . Same error. I also tried `DialogResult::Cancel` and i get 2 errors: one says `Cancel is an undeclared identifier` , and the other:
`C2039: 'Cancel' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::DialogResult'`

Comment: try above (sorry, i used C# syntax, not c++/cli)

Comment: @ryrich Partially works. Now it always gets to `return`. Maybe that's because in button Start Game i have the code `NewGame::Hide();` ? Maybe this returns `Cancel` ?

Comment: @AlaaM. Try setting the DialogResult property of your Start Game button. For example, if button name is `startGameBtn`, `startGameBtn.DialogResult = System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK` This ensures when clicking the Start Game button, it will return the OK enumeration to your form.

Comment: @ryrich Smart! OK so `Button.DialogResult` didn't work. I tried `DialogResult = ...` and it worked! Thank you !